# JWT signature does not match locally computed signature but signing key is the same as generated

Tags: java, rest, filter, jwt, secret-key

I am working in a REST endpoint and I'm implementing JWT as a form to validate session and inativity. I generate a token with a short expire date and a refresh token with a longer one, to stay connected the user will update the token with the refresh token and keep connected.
The problem is, when the user logs in it generates both tokens with the same signature but when I was working at the request filter I can validate the token but the refresh token presents this exception:

> "JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity
> cannot be asserted and should not be trusted."

The code that generate both tokens is this:

```
public String generateToken(String usuario, String session, Date expiration, Map claims) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        
        String secret = jpaService.getSecret();        
        SecretKey secretKey = generateSecretKey(secret + session);
        System.out.println("SecretKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded())); // This is for checking if the secret key is the same
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setHeaderParam(Header.TYPE, Header.JWT_TYPE)
                .setSubject(usuario)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuer(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiration) // Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusWeeks(1).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
                .signWith(secretKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)                
                .compact();
        
        return token;
    }
```

As I said, the regular token can be read, but the refresh token can't. This is the code in the request filter that reads the token:

```
private void readToken(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, String secret, String session, String token, String message) {
        try {
            SecretKey secretKey = security.generateSecretKey(secret + session);
            System.out.println("SecretKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded())); // This is for checking if the secret key is the same
            Jws jws = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            System.out.println("jws" + jws);
            System.out.println("Body JWS: " + jws.getBody());
            
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException | MalformedJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException | SignatureException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION" + ex);
            JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
            json.addProperty("serviceResponse", "ERROR");
            json.addProperty("message", message);
            json.addProperty("exception", ex.getMessage());
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(json.toString()).build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already solved the issue, the token I was passing through the HTTP request didn't had the 'Bearer' in front of it so it wasn't being set as the Authorization header, the rest of the code works just fine